# How to reset/unset Lando composer github-oauth in window 10

Tags: composer-php, lando

I have set the auth token in [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/) composer with command “lando composer config --global --auth github-oauth.github.com ghp_4Gfo*******JG3”. but it's invalid,when I type “Lando composer install” or any other Lando Composer command, it types following message:

```
 [UnexpectedValueException] 
 Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters: "ghp_4Gfo*******JG3"
```

and I can't reset it by "lando composer config -g --unset github.oauth.github.com",with showing the same message.
How can I reset/unset the auth token? and Where is the setting file? I can't find it in C:/User/Username/.lando/
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Clean the auth.json file:

`lando ssh -u root -s container`

`cd /var/www/.composer`

`echo '{}' > auth.json`

In my case:

`lando ssh -u root -s appserver`

`cd /var/www/.composer`

`echo '{}' > auth.json`